# PHP loop on dynamic inserts

Tags: php

I asked a similar question recently, but I am trying to break down my problem to its core so that understanding it is a lot simpler.

Basically, I have dynamically created divs that each have their own ability for queries and Inserts.

What I don't understand quite well is how to go about looping through my code to make dynamic insert statements.

Let's take a portion of my code:

`"UPDATE hobbies SET assignedto = '$hobbygroupname' WHERE hobbyname = '$hobbygroupassign'"`

The variable `$hobbygroupname` gives me an array of everyone that is in my `friendgroups`table column `hobbygroup`.

However, when used as an insert statement, `$hobbygroupname` winds up adding the last value to my database.

What I would like to know is how I might properly arrange a for loop so that the instance of `$hobbygroupname` only adds the value that is appropriate, going down the list of columns.

**My full code**:

```
            $groupsearch = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM friendgroups");
            while ($tebow = $groupsearch->fetch_assoc()){
                $ming = $tebow['uid'];
                $sing = $tebow['hobbygroup'];

                if(isset($_POST['hobby_submission'])){
                    $hobbygroupassign = strip_tags($_POST['hobbygroupassign']);
                    $hobbygroupname = $sing;
                    $hobbyrun = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM hobbies WHERE hobbyname = '$hobbygroupassign'");

                            $hobbyput = $dbcon->query("UPDATE hobbies SET assignedto = '$hobbygroupname' WHERE hobbyname = '$hobbygroupassign'");

                }
```

Comment: Fix quotes please.

Comment: `$groupsearch` has bad syntax;  you have double quotes within you SQL string.

Comment: Something is wrong with your first line, the concatenation doesn't work like this.

Comment: @u_mulder it's a good feeling when everyone points out the same issue at the same time. hah. `:-)`